# How can I get the value of an input of two or more rows through the indexes which I got before?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem:
I have a table and in the first row you can type in some inputs.
I want to get the value of these inputs through the different indexes.
The different indexes I got like this:

```
        var arr = resultSums;
        var largest = [0];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var comp = (arr[i] - largest[0]) > 0;
            if (comp) {
                largest = [];
                largest.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }

        var arrIndex = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var comp = arr[i] - largest[0] == 0;
            if (comp) {
                arrIndex.push(i);
            }
        }
```

How can I get the different values of the input (in the first row of the table) if the result of this upper code is for example "2,4"?
Table name: "myTable"

HTML of the table:

```
"                <table class="table" id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <h4>Criteria</h4>
                    </th>
                    <th><input placeholder="Selection 1" :></th>
                    <th><input placeholder="Selection 2" :></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input placeholder="Criterium 1">
                        <select style="margin-left: 2px;">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>9</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>9</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input placeholder="Criterium 2">
                        <select style="margin-left: 2px;">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>9</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>9</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>"
```

My previous function in JS multiplies the different options and with the upper JS code I get the indexes. And now I want to get the value of the inputs of these indexes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you publish the html code ?

Comment: The html of the table?
The table is responsive so you can add rows and collumns by a button but I will edit my post that you can see the structure of the table

Comment: Added the code of the first row of the table

Comment: I can not see the relation between the javascript code that you wrote and your need

Comment: Ok my bad sry! I thought the HTML code I uploaded is enough to understand but now I realise it isnt! I will edit my post again sry

Comment: Now it should be more understandable I think

Comment: well.. now i saw it that. i hope my answer help you to know how to interact with the DOM in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I Already did a changes on the HTML and like Ismailm u can not see 100% the relation so i create a new one for get the values of inputs inside the table as an array.

sorry for english.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

    function getValuesOfInputsFill() {
      //Storage of values per row
      const valuesPerRow = [];
      //Fixed index if it a new row.
      var fixedIndex = -1;
      //Iterate ( Loop ) over cells
      document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td').forEach((c,index)=>{
        //Inner child element scope.
        let childScope = c.children[0];
        //Is a new row ?
        if ( c.scope === "row" ) {
          fixedIndex += 1;
          //Push the title.
          valuesPerRow.push( {row: childScope.innerText } );
        } else {
          //Establish a property name and then set the value.
          let propertyName = childScope.placeholder.replace(' ','').trim();
          valuesPerRow[fixedIndex][propertyName] = childScope.value;
        }
      });
      //Return the storage fullfilled.
      return valuesPerRow;
    }
    
    // Listener to the button for get the values of whole table.
    
    document.querySelector('.btn__get').addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
       const result = getValuesOfInputsFill();
       console.dir(result);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row"><h4>Criteria 1</h4></td>
        <td><input placeholder="Selection 1" ></td>
        <td><input placeholder="Selection 2" ></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td scope="row"><h4>Criteria 2</h4></td>
        <td><input placeholder="Selection 1" ></td>
        <td><input placeholder="Selection 2" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row"><h4>Criteria 3</h4></td>
        <td><input placeholder="Selection 1" ></td>
        <td><input placeholder="Selection 2" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 
 <button class="btn__get">Get values</button>
```